# Redshift's pg_catalog schema missing in DBeaver

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I am using default DBeaver settings in Mac OS but when I connect to Redshift, the pg_catalog  schema & system tables within are missing in DBeaver Project browser. I tried looking into DBeaver docs, but I could not find any useful to toggle this.

I also tried checking the settings if we could manually select any schemas but it did not help. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: can you manually select pg_catalog?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On newer versions of DBeaver (e.g. 7.1.1), if you cannot see the `pg_catalog` schema, please go into *Edit Connection* and check that:

- *Navigator View* is set to *Advanced*.
- Under *Customize*, that *Show system objects* is enabled.

[image: Edit Connection dialog with General and Navigator View highlighted and Customize dialog shown]

Answer (score 0):

You can get all Postgres system-related schemas while adding a connection in DBeaver by selecting **Miscellaneous checkboxes** on General tab.

[image: Connection]